# Monit: сделать перезагрузку сервера при большой нагрузке на процессор

Tags: ubuntu, monit

Как сделать, чтобы monit отслеживал нагрузку на сервер, и, если она больше определённого значения, то перезапускал сервер?

У меня такой вариант:

```
if cpu usage (user) > 70% then reboot
if cpu usage (system) > 30% then reboot
```

У меня сервер перезапускается командой `reboot`, правильная ли команда выше?

Answer (score 1):

согласно информации, приведённой в [примерах](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples), часть команды до директивы `then` — правильная.

а вот после `then`, для выполнения команды оболочки следует использовать директиву `exec`. и надёжнее будет указать полный путь к файлу `reboot`. если этот путь `/sbin/reboot`, то команды могут выглядеть так:

```
if cpu usage (user) > 70% then exec /sbin/reboot
if cpu usage (system) > 30% then exec /sbin/reboot
```